# Completely change error message in SQL Server (inside Trigger)

Tags: sql-server, exception, triggers, custom-errors

I am trying to add a user-friendly message to a trigger's catch section.
The trigger will fire when the record already exists.

I wish to change the error message completely, is that possible?
I've been playing with throw, raiserror and sp_addmessage but until now I am only able to change a part of the message. I wish to change all of it.

This is the current message and underlined is the only part of it i want to display.
[image]

Code:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Begin Try
Insert into dbo.Crop
select * from Inserted
End Try
Begin Catch
RAISERROR  ('This record already exists.',16,1)
--Throw 50002, 'This record already exists.', 1;
    --RAISERROR  (50002,16,1)
End Catch

END
```

Somewhere else:

```
Use master
go
EXEC sp_addmessage 50002, 16, N'This record already exists';
```

Comment: This kind of error should be handled in your application code (.net or anything) and not in a stored procedure !

Comment: Hi Thomas,
Sadly my front-end in this case is an ACCESS linked-table which doesn't allow me to add VBA or Macros.
So apparently I am stuck with doing it in a trigger, afaik.